# JavaScript/jQuery: Array - For In Loop Return Value of Lowest Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

Here is what I have, I've tried to do it in a for in loop and it's not quite doing what I need it to do. I thought of doing $.each, but I wasn't sure how to get past just looping the array.

```
var myKeys = [{a:1, b:10}, {a:5, b:8}, {a:3, b:2}, {a:1, b:6}];
```

I want to run a function that searches thru the keys. Finds the lowest 'b' value, and then returns the 'a' key. In the case above: search and find 2, but return 3 ( {a:3, b:2} )

Tried this, but I just get returned 0, 1, 2, 3 (all the keys) and their index.

```
for (var key in myKeys) {
    if (myKeys.hasOwnProperty(myKeys[key]) <= 2) {
    console.log(key);
  }
}
```

Any insight on how to fix it would be great. If it were just the 1 value, I wouldn't have a problem. It's that there are multiple and I need to return the other value.

Comment: myKeys.hasOwnProperty(myKeys[key])  return a bollean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to run a function that searches thru the keys. Finds the lowest
>   'b' value, and then returns the 'a' key. In the case above: search and
>   find 2, but return 3

You can create variables `index`, `n` to store index of element having `"b"` property of object and value of `"b"` property. Use `for..of` loop to iterate `Array.prototype.entries()` of array. Check if current object of array `"b"` property is less than previous object `"b"` property. Use `index` following `for..of` loop to get `"a"` property of `myKeys[index]`.

```js
var myKeys = [{a:1, b:10}, {a:5, b:8}, {a:3, b:2}, {a:1, b:6}];

let n = index = 0;

for (let [key, prop, curr] of myKeys.entries()) {
  if (({b:curr} = prop, curr) < n || !n) [n, index] = [curr, key];
}

let {a} = myKeys[index]; // call `delete n` here if `n`:`2` not needed;

console.log({a});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var myKeys = [{a:1, b:10}, {a:5, b:8}, {a:3, b:2}, {a:1, b:6}];
var min = myKeys.reduce(function(current, previous){
  return (current.b > -1 && current.b < previous.b ? current : previous);
}, {a:-1, b:-1});
console.log(min);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Somehting like this?

```js
var myKeys = [{a:1, b:10}, {a:5, b:8}, {a:3, b:2}, {a:1, b:6}];

for (var x = 0; x < myKeys.length; x++) {
    var this_key = myKeys[x];

    for (var key in this_key) {
        if (this_key[key] <= 2) {
            console.log(key);
        }
    }

};
```